# how to push multiple response streams in php using http/2 server-push

Tags: php, server-push, http2

How do I tell my server to open a new [push stream](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#StreamsLayer) inside a php script? The old simple way with

```
echo "Content";
```

will obviously not work with [HTTP/2 server push](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PushResources) anymore. Because only the business logic knows what resources are needed in the future.
Is there a module required for that or is this available in PHP7?

Comment: Depending on your edge server you add a hint in the form a response header. You may get the details soon enough in a response. I just wanted you to note that HTTP2/Push is for cacheable resources. Using PHP to  serve those makes sense in many contexts, but a huge crowd out there would let the "edge" web server (NginX, Jetty, Apache, ShimmerCat) to handle all cacheable content.

Comment: Also, I hope somebody proves me wrong, but I don't know of any middleware protocol (other than HTTP/2 or SPDY itself of course) that would allow the middleware to actively set the contents of the pushed streams. In practice, this means that your PHP code would have to generate the pushed content as if it were answering a request.

Comment: Yes I'd like to see something like this http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.2.v20140723/spdy-implementing-push.html

Comment: Also look at this https://www.igvita.com/2013/06/12/innovating-with-http-2.0-server-push/ that implements what I want to do in node I guess